# C# How to convert CSV data into JSON data

Tags: c#, json, csv, json.net

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVoAR.png)

The CSV file is incredibly simple (i thought i start off simple - 2 rows):

Name,Address
Dave,example street 1
Charlie,example street 2
jordan,Example 3
Ross,simple Street

I am trying to print out the CSV data into JSON. I know i am missing a few things but I'm just not sure what. Any help would be great

The plan is to add functionality to change the data to XML, but for now i just need it to change CSV data into JSON.

Comment: Code is text, could you add your code to the question?

Comment: Move the serialize code outside the foreach loop. In short you need to serialize csv

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `var csv = new List<string[]>();` to `var csv = new List<PeopleDataClass>();`.

Do not convert in foreach everytime. In foreach just parse line and push top list.

Then you  will have `PeopleDataClass` list. You can convert to json now.

```
var csv = new List<PeopleDataClass>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\kordiseps\Desktop\New Text Document.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    csv.Add(new PeopleDataClass
    {
        Address = line.Split(',')[0],
        Name = line.Split(',')[1]
    });
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csv);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, how do i actually return the newly serialized JSON data? 
When I run that, nothing happens because i haven't returned anything yet. https://i.gyazo.com/39dc2ef19b2e4c1678afa6aaff9f07e6.png

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine(json);` below `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csv);`

Comment: What do you want to with this json? Save to file?